# React native map integration

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

I am trying to integrate map in react native. I am following the below tutorial. 
https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps

I gone through all the installation instruction. 
I am using `react-native version : 0.44.0` and `react-native-map version : 0.13.0`
I made sure that `react-native-link` is linked with android and iOS. 
While rendering the mapview in ios simulator, map is not showing and only i am able to a blank map with red outline.

Please check my below code and let me know, where i am wrong.

```
var MapView = require('react-native-maps');
<MapView
    initialRegion={{
    latitude: 37.78825,
    longitude: -122.4324,
    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
    }}
/>
```

Comment: I suggest you to check if it works for you with Genymotion first. Do you use an emulator or a physical device?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a View and some heights and ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject

```
<View style={{height:400}}>
    <MapView 
         style={{ ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,height:400 }}
         initialRegion={{
             latitude: 37.78825,
             longitude: -122.4324,
             latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
             longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
         }}
    />
</View>
```

Comment: Hello, @jeremie, thanks for reply. Sorry to say you that it's not working for me. I have already gone through this code. also i update react-native-map version to 0.16.0. But there is no effect.

Comment: Finally i solved this issue after updating RN to 0.47.1. 
also i update map version to 0.16.1. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to include your Google Maps API key in the AndroidManifest.xml.